# jqgrid: Event after Save

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I wanted to do some additional ajax processing after I edit a row and saving the changes by pressing Enter key.  How do I do this?

I have this code but it only works when I pressed the Save button on Inline nav

```
$("#"+tbl).jqGrid('inlineNav',"#"+nav, {
        edittext:"Edit",
        addtext:"Add", 
        savetext:"Save", 
        canceltext:"Cancel",
        addParams:{
            useDefValues: true,
            addRowParams: {
                keys: true,
                extraparam:{cid:$_GET['cid'], tbl:tbl},
                oneditfunc: setFareDefaults
            }

        },
        editParams:{
            keys: true,
            extraparam:{cid:$_GET['cid'], tbl:tbl},
            aftersavefunc : function(id){

                $.post('svc/check_pub.php',{cid:$_GET["cid"]}, function(data){
                    var ret = parseInt(data);
                    if(ret) {
                        $("#pubtxt").html("<small style='font-weight:normal;float:right;color:orange'>[this campaign is unpublished]</small>");
                    } else {
                        $("#pubtxt").html("<small style='font-weight:normal;float:right;color:green'>[this campaign is published]</small>");
                    }
                },"text");  
            },

            oneditfunc: setFareDefaults
        }

    });
```

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use? It's unclear from the posted code why you want reload grid only answer editing and not after adding of new row. You wrote "it only works when I pressed the Save button". What in not work exactly? Will be the `aftersavefunc` not called? Will be `"#pubtxt"` not refreshed? Will be grid not reloaded? Which `datatype` has the grid? Do you use `loadonce: true` option?

Comment: Hi Oleg, I edited my script, removed the reloadGrid for now. 

jQgrid version is 4.4.0, loadonce is set to false.  #pubtext is not refreshing when i use Enter key after editing the row.  It only refreshes when i press the inline Save.

Comment: I tried again, basically, the aftersavefunc is not being called.

Comment: `inlineNav` is very buggy in old versions. I posted many bug fixes which are included in jqGrid 4.4.5. Could you repeat the same test with jqGrid 4.4.5? If you can replace jqGrid, then you should at least replace (overwrite) the code of `inlineNav`. Moreover if you see that `aftersavefunc` was not called you should verify HTTP traffic: is request to save was sent? is the response from the server contains successful HTTP status code?

Comment: Save was actually successful. I just wanted do an extra processing after the Save.  

I will try updating my jqGrid and try again.  Thanks

Comment: Hi @Oleg I had upgraded my jqGrid to 4.4.5 still the `aftersavefunc` still not being called when `Enter` key is pressed.

Comment: If the server response really contains successful HTTP code the method `aftersavefunc` must be called. I tested your code and con't reproduce tha problem which you described. I used `aftersavefunc: function () { alert("in aftersavefunc);} ` and I could always see alert message. So you should debug the problem yourself. You should set breakpoint on [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L301) of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. Independent from the tests I would recommend you to insert `aftersavefunc` in `addParams.addRowParams` too.